# Notebook compatibility

Tags: asus, acer

I'm currently using a Notebook with Ubuntu and and since like it, I would like to keep using this Ubuntu... :-)

Unfortunately I can't find any notebook for sale with Ubuntu in Portugal. I was looking at this one with windows 8: ACER ES1-512-C29D and ASUS F553MA-SX361B, but I can't find whether they work with Ubuntu or not.

How can I find out if they are compatible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to go to a computer shop which sells one of your models and ask whether you may boot Ubuntu from an USB stick in order to test if everything's fine (emphasize that you're not going to change anything at the computer at all - I've experienced that many resellers have never heard of Ubuntu, let alone used it.)

You can put an Ubuntu ISO on an USB stick using utilities like [UNetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/). When the shop allows you to test it, boot from the USB stick and select the menu option "try without installation".

---

Another way to find out whether Ubuntu works with this computer is to find out which components are installed in this machine and search the internet on known problems to these devices (e.g. graphics card, LAN card, WiFi card). Some computers are even certified to work with Ubuntu in the Ubuntu Certification Program, in which Asus participates.

However, this won't 100%ly assure that it will actually work, so first method is preferable.

---

In general, I've made the experience that Ubuntu will run on most systems almost without problems, as long as you don't use and exotic hardware, whose manufacturer only provides Windows drivers.

You could also search for computers that come preinstalled with ANY linux-based OS. They all use a release of the Linux kernel, which does all the hardware interaction, so it shouldn't matter whether you use Ubuntu or, let's say, SUSE Linux, which was preinstalled on my Notebook when I bought it.

Although I have to say that this is not always true: Only after waiting two months for the shipment of said notebook, I learned that HP sent me a device whose hardware components are not completely Linux-compatible: Bluetooth, SD-Card reader and certain Fn keys don't or only partially do work.

Comment: Asus does participate in Ubuntu certification. A list of certified Asus laptops can be found [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/make/Asus/?category=Desktop&category=Laptop). In fact, they used to have a laptop featured on the Ubuntu website some time ago.

Comment: Boot Ubuntu from an USB stick, that Is a very good idea ... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although the seller did not let me test the software I ended up buying an ASUS F553M. I installed Ubuntu in accordance with the instructions given here and the computer is running almost 100%. With the exception of not turning off, is locked in the message "* will now halt", and consequent problems in restarting, all hardware seems to work. Thank you, Vasco Reis –  Vasco Reis

Answer (score 0):

Asus F553M works with Ubuntu on USB but after installation you can't run computer. It's a problem with all Linux systems on F553M. I have tried Ubuntu, Debian, Fedora, Arch, CentOS and OpenSUSE. OpenSUSE as only one run on F553M but it needs long time to start (about 1min) and there is many other problems.

Answer (score 0):

After all, i'm not the only one having these problems. I also had this problem in the boot that does not start without the usb device and ubuntu (and mint 17.1) does not turn off completely. Well I am not a pro but i already used Linux distros enough and had never had so much trouble until try to install linux on this asus. The best way I could find to let Linux working more or less, was installing linux mint debian version and every time you turn on the pc you immediately press Esc key and then appears a small boot menu and you choose Linux that it install.( i don't know well how it is written because it has been a while). With this you can use the linux, but for example, screen brightness controls do not work but now turns off completely is possible! As I say, not everything is working 100% but is working! Try waiting for the ubuntu 15:04 to see if it is already improved compatibility, but for now you can try this method.

Answer (score 0):

The current link to Ubuntu-certified hardware is here: https://certification.ubuntu.com/

Asus no longer appears to be participating, which means it will be hit or miss, or you'll need the full component spec list and go through it all one by one to ensure it isn't Windows-specific hardware.

Older/established model lines tend to do better, in general, as it has given time for open source developers to create drivers and get them into the mainline kernel.

It would be nice to have a definitive list of hardware manufacturers who are supportive of Open Source, and to what degree? (e.g., 3 levels: open source hardware (and software), open source software/drivers, or proprietary binaries for open source platforms (e.g., nVidia)) but I am unaware of anyone maintaining such a list.

Just having that list would be an element of market pressure that could help manufacturers see the value in supporting or adopting open source philosophies.