# Hardware check for new laptop

Tags: nvidia, lenovo

I purchased a used laptop (Lenovo Z710 Intel i7-4710MQ 2.50GHz 16GB Ram 1TB SSHD NVIDIA 840M WIN 8.1 Laptop) It is not a touch screen and does have a backlit keyboard.

My question: Is there a site that shows if all my hardware is certified for use with Ubuntu? On Lenovo's site there is a list of systems that are certified with various builds but is appears older and my laptop was not listed.

Specifically I want to make sure my Hybrid hard-drive and video card are compatible. I have successfully installed Ubuntu on several older laptops without trouble but wanted to check on this newest one while it is still in transit to me.

Comment: I did already search the certified hardware list on ubuntu.com and did not find my laptop there either.

Comment: boot the live USB and test it out =)

Comment: It is in the mail system so I can't just yet...I am excited about it hence my lack of patience. :-) I will be giving it a shot once it arrives. I have read quite a few posts about dual booting with Win 8.1. I am now researching what impacts if any upgrading to win 10 will have. With the win install on a separate partition I think there will not be any issues with existing dual boot systems.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Notebook compatibility](http://askubuntu.com/questions/554772/notebook-compatibility)

Comment: If you upgrade yo win 10 you will most probably encounter a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I regularly install Ubuntu on computers and I've never encountered a device it didn't work on. According to the specs you've given I think it's going to work. Nevertheless if you're in doubt take a live cd/usb, boot it and you'll see what happens. As long as you don't install from the live cd/usb it won't hurt your computer. If you like how it works then you can install from it. About everything to know about the live cd is available [on this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD).

Comment: cd are old school and "never encountered a device it didn't work on" really ?

Comment: It is called a live cd although it is actually a live dvd. Live cd's and live usb's are equally good. And yes, so far all installs I did on modern computers even those with specs not as good as posted did work. Sometimes a little tinkering was needed especially in the wireless department but still none failed to boot.